# QuickBasic Grammar using ANTLR

Tags: antlr

I'm using ANTLR and the following grammar:

```
grammar QuickBasic;

options 
{
    language = 'CSharp2';
    output = AST;
}

parse
    :    block EOF
    ;

block
    :    (labelStatement | labeledStatement | statement)*
    ;

labelStatement
    :    label ':' -> ^(label)
    ;

labeledStatement
    :    label statement -> ^(label statement)
    ;

statement
    :    assignment
    ;

assignment
    :    IDENTIFIER '=' value -> ^('=' IDENTIFIER value)
    ;

value
    :    (IDENTIFIER | constant)
    ;

constant 
    :    (STRING | INTEGER | REAL)
    ;

label
    :    (ALPHANUMERIC)+
    ;

IDENTIFIER
    :    LETTER (ALPHANUMERIC)*
    ;

REAL
    :    (INTEGER '.' NATURAL)
    ;

INTEGER
    :    ('-')? NATURAL
    ; 

SPACE
    :    (' ' | '\t' | '\r' | '\n' | '\u000C') {Skip();} 
    ;

STRING
    :    '"' ('""' | ~'"')* '"'
    ;

fragment NATURAL
    :    (DIGIT)+
    ;   

fragment ALPHANUMERIC
    :    (DIGIT | LETTER)
    ;

fragment DIGIT
    :    '0'..'9'
    ;

fragment LETTER
    :    ('a'..'z' | 'A'..'Z')
    ;
```

With this, I'm trying to parse the folowing file:

```
PI = 3.141592
CALC:
100 A = 1
```

What happens next is that line 'CALC:' should be a label, but it tries to parse as a statement, and gives me an error saying mismatched input ':' expecting '='.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `label` rule is wrong:

```
label
    :    (ALPHANUMERIC)+
    ;
```

because `ALPHANUMERIC` is a fragment-lexer rule, it can only be used by other lexer rules, never in parser rules. Your lexer will only produce the following tokens: `IDENTIFIER`, `INTEGER`, `REAL` and `STRING` (plus the literal tokens in your parser rules, like `'.'` etc.): making those the only lexer rules you can use in your parser rules.

Also, you should only create AST's that have a single *unique* root. You're trying to create a root for both `labelStatement` and `labeledStatement` that wouldn't make it distinguishable from other parser rules: making the tree walker (either ANTLR's tree walker, or your own tree walker) having problems when they encounter the root of such an AST. Much better to create (imaginary) `LABEL` and `LABELED_STAT` tokens an make them the root of your AST:

```
...

tokens 
{
    LABEL;
    LABELED_STAT;
}

parse
    :    block EOF
    ;

...

labelStatement
    :    label ':' -> ^(LABEL label)
    ;

labeledStatement
    :    label statement -> ^(LABELED_STAT label statement)
    ;

...

label
    :    IDENTIFIER
    |    INTEGER
    ;
```

This will create the following AST:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

try using lower case skip() instead of Skip() and something like this to allow multiple spaces

```
SPACE
    :    (' ' | '\t' | '\u000C' | '\n' | '\r' )+ {skip();} 
    ;
```

Comment: I thought "skip()" was just a method on the base class "Lexer" for java... as I'm using c#, the method is "Skip()". Is that correct?

Comment: No, `Skip()` instead of `skip()` and adding a `+` in the `SPACE` rule wouldn't make a difference. (@JonathasCosta, yes, you are correct).